# Error: The type or namespace name ... does not exist in the namespace / could not be found

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-strategy, debugging

I have written some code to verify, that a user can login to a hotel booking platform & I also added a verification step. I get an error
on the `Assert.IsTrue()` Method. Every other thing is fine in the code.

I did some research for a possible solution before stopping by.

Here is the solution I found on `StackOverflow`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695595/assert-method-error

I have added `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` to my project references and also added

`using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; & using NUnit.Framework;` to my Using section of the code.

I get the following errors:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
> Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) PremierInn_Valid_User_Login c:\users\XXXX\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PremierInn_Valid_User_Login\PremierInn_Valid_User_Login\Program.cs 5 Active

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) PremierInn_Valid_User_Login c:\users\XXXX\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PremierInn_Valid_User_Login\PremierInn_Valid_User_Login\Program.cs 6 Active

I get the same error after removing the bindings -

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; & using NUnit.Framework.

And, finally here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PremierInn_Valid_User_Login {
 class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {

   //Instantiate Firefox Driver
   var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://secure.premierinn.com/en/mypremierinn/home.action");

   //Enter User Name - My Email Address
   var user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm.username"));
   user.SendKeys("abcdefg@gmail.com");

   //Enter Password - Account Pasword
   var pass = driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm.password"));
   pass.SendKeys("Testing123");

   //Click on Login button
   driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm.button")).Click();

   var loggedInHeader = driver.FindElement(By.Id("body-inner"));
   Assert.IsTrue(loggedInHeader.Displayed, "The user was able to successfully login.");

  }
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: formatted to make it readable.

Comment: are you sure abcdefg@gmail.com is a valid username?

Comment: Thank you Corey for your response. I have tried with a different email address & I can confirm that that is not where the error is coming from.

Thank very much once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First decide on what testing framework to use either MSTest or NUnit. You cannot or should not use both at the same time.

Both test frameworks expect you use a test-class and not `Main()` as you are doing. If you follow the getting started guides you should end up with a full test-class in which you can use the Assert function.

Typical it would look something like this

```
using System;  
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;  

namespace Tests  
{  
    [TestClass]  
    public class YourTestClass  
    {  
        [TestMethod]  
        public void TestMethod1()  
        { 
          // Arrange
          // Act
          // Assert
          Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }  
    }  
}
```

If you want to use `Assert` without a test-class [suggested is to replace it with an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353154/using-asserts-outside-of-unit-test). Exceptions is also what the Assert throws when it fails.

Other reads:

- MSTest creating and Running Unit Tests: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx
- NUnit getting started: https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=getStarted&r=2.2.10
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nnaderi/2007/02/01/comparing-the-mstest-and-nunit-frameworks/